# NSString stringWithContentOfFile

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, nsstring

In the Apple developer documents it says that `stringWithContentOfFile:` is Depreciated in iOS2.0 but it also says available available on iOS4 so which is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable to use any deprecated methods. You should use:

`stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error`

Answer (score 0):

Yes: deprecated doesn't mean it's not there any more, it means 1. Apple recommends you don't use it, and 2. it may disappear in later versions.

Regarding `NSString`'s `stringWithContentOfFile:`, yes, it is indeed still here in iOS 4.